# MongoDB repairDatabase returns unauthorized

Tags: mongodb, unauthorized

I add a user with role

```
["readWrite","dbAdmin","clusterAdmin", "readWriteAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase"]
```

but when i log in mongodb, and execute `db.repairDatabase()`, i get the error:

```
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized"}.
```

In the beginning, I just added role `readWrite` and `dbAdmin`, and added more and more roles, but encountered that error.

I read https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#built-in-roles, and it seems we can use `repairDatabase` when we have the dbAdmin role. But this doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me out of this problem? If you want more information, please tell me.

here is my test script:

```
CONTROLLER_IP=myip
DB_PWD='password'

openstack-config --set /etc/mongodb.conf '' auth false
systemctl restart mongod

mongo --host ${CONTROLLER_IP} --eval 'db = db.getSiblingDB("admin");db.removeUser("admin")' 
mongo --host ${CONTROLLER_IP} --eval 'db = db.getSiblingDB("ceilometer");db.removeUser("ceilometer")' 
systemctl restart mongod

mongo --host ${CONTROLLER_IP} --eval 'db = db.getSiblingDB("admin");db.addUser({user: "admin",pwd: "'${DB_PWD}'",roles: [ "readWrite","dbAdmin","clusterAdmin","readWriteAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase"]})' 
mongo --host ${CONTROLLER_IP} --eval 'db = db.getSiblingDB("ceilometer");db.addUser({user: "ceilometer",pwd: "'${DB_PWD}'",roles: [ "readWrite","dbAdmin","clusterAdmin", "readWriteAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase" ]})'

openstack-config --set /etc/mongodb.conf '' auth true
systemctl restart mongod

mongo ceilometer -uceilometer -p
```

Comment: Can you try with root role? just update the existing user with root role or create a new  user with root role.

Comment: @harshavmb I did add role root, now my roles are `root, readWrite, dbAdmin, clusterAdmin,readWriteAnyDatabase, dbAdminAnyDatabase`,but it does not work for me. my os is **centos 7** and mongodb version is **2.4.9**

Answer (score 1):

It's a MongoDB's bug in version 2.4.9(https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11027), I follow https://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/ and upgrade to version 2.6.11, it works.